# How to remove ending blank paragraph from string?

Tags: php, html, regex

In my database, some text are stored as

```
<p>texxxxxxxxxxt1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>textttttttttt2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>teeeeeeeeeext3</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

when i'm displaying them, i'd like those final blanks to be removed... I've already tried many things but none of them is working...
I thought about

```
$content = preg_replace("#(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>)+$#", '', $content);
$content = preg_replace("#(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\r)+$#", '', $content);
```

and others but they doesn't work because of the line break... any idea? 
end result should be something like

```
<p>texxxxxxxxxxt1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>textttttttttt2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>teeeeeeeeeext3</p>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to use regex, just use regular replace.

Comment: if i'm using str_replace, I'm losing breaks between texts, doesn't work... I want only finals empty paragraph to disappear, not the others...

Comment: Question is, what are `&nbsp;` doing in a DB in the first place? Storing tags in a DB is not recommended and can be handled easily during the output query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you only have `<p>&nbsp;</p>` at the end, you can use this:

```
([\n\r]*<p>&nbsp;<\/p>)*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rS3uY3/1

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are my winner! :D

Answer (score 0):

How about breaking the string into an array (on newlines), and then looping from the back of the array. If it is equal to `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, then pop it off the array. Finally join the array back into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here a recursive function:

```
<?php
$str = "<p>text1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>text3</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>";
$substring = "<p>&nbsp;</p>";

function magic($str, $substring) {
    $str = trim(rtrim($str));
    if (substr($str, (strlen($str) - strlen($substring)), strlen($str)) == $substring) {
        $str = trim(rtrim(substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - strlen($substring))));
        $str = magic($str, $substring);
    }
    return $str;
}

echo magic($str, $substring);
```